The app installed on your device is not recognized - how to overcome?
I am getting this info when installing apps from APK on my device, Android 12. This app is for US, but my Google Play account is not, so I guess this inconsistency causes this error.
I was thinking it is Play Protect that causes this error, but as it seems I was wrong. Disabling the Play Protect didn't solve the error.

Any suggestions what to do?
P.S. Obviously pressing "search on play" gives nothing, as the app is not available for my account locale, so it is not offered in the search list.

The screenshot seems to be from PlayStore app. Does it directly opens when you start the app? If yes then the app seems to perform some checks and then redirect you to PlayStore app.

Does it directly opens when you start the app? it shows the splash screen for a second then immediately redirects to that page, pictured on the screenshot. So, the answer is "no', the app is not opened.

I am not sure if your "no" is correct. An app runs code before the UI is loaded. The splash screen shows that parts of the app are already loaded. In my understanding Play Protect works before the has been started at all, because it intent hk protect against malicious apps and therefore has to prevent to execute even a tiny bit of that app. In conclusion my guess hasn't changed. This page was cause by something embedded in the app itself. I don't think you can change it without modifying or hacking the app itself.

Yeah, looks like you are correct. I installed this 7-11 app from APK on another phone with no Google Account, and when I start the app it also right from the splash screen redirects me to the Google Play where I see Sign in prompt. Regardless, I want to bypass this restriction. Do you think it is impossible without repacking the apk file?
